Como ignorar mayuscula y minuscula en bash
Buenas la parte que dice find -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*'$etiqueta'.*
Me gustaría que no distinga entre minúscula y mayúscula, pero no he podido lograrlo ni con la opción -iname o bien -i, yo use  find -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.'$etiqueta'. porque es la que mejor se adaptaba pero no se si hay otra forma, se trata de buscar archivos en una carpeta que tengan la etiqueta en alguna parte del nombre del archivo, por eso use esa, gracias!
read -p "¿Qué etiqueta desea buscar? " etiqueta
while [ -z $etiqueta ];do
        echo "No es un dato valido, por favor vuelva a intentarlo."
        read -p "¿Qué etiqueta desea buscar? " etiqueta
done

if [ ! `find -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*'$etiqueta'.*' |wc -l` -eq 0 ];then
        echo "Se econtraron "`find -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*'$etiqueta'.*' |wc -l`" resultados con la etiqueta '$etiqueta'."
        echo "Estos son los resultados:"
        find -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*'$etiqueta'.*'
else
        echo "No se encontraron resultados con la etiqueta '$etiqueta'."
fi


En vez de -regex usa -iregex

Muchas gracias @PsychoMx!! Era eso.

este problema se puede resolver usando -iregex en vez de -regex. El código se vería de esta forma:
Código
read -p "¿Qué etiqueta desea buscar? " etiqueta
while [ -z "$etiqueta" ]; do
    echo "No es un dato valido, por favor vuelva a intentarlo."
    read -p "¿Qué etiqueta desea buscar? " etiqueta
done

resultados=$(find . -regextype posix-egrep -iregex '.*'"$etiqueta"'.*' | wc -l)

if [ $resultados -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Se encontraron $resultados resultados con la etiqueta '$etiqueta'."
    echo "Estos son los resultados:"
    find . -regextype posix-egrep -iregex '.*'"$etiqueta"'.*'
else
    echo "No se encontraron resultados con la etiqueta '$etiqueta'."
fi

Explicación: usar -iregrex ayuda a buscar textos sin importar las mayúsculas o minúsculas a diferencia de -regrex que con este si importa.
Ojo: Agregue esta respuesta para responder a la pregunta, pero en el comentario de arriba de PychoMx se explica el cambio de los comandos, solo quise mostrar como se vería en el código para más compresión.

Espero sea de ayuda
